# Matrix version of rasterToPoints?

Tags: r, matrix

Anyone know of a non-raster method to achieve the following?

```
require(raster)
d = data.frame(rasterToPoints(raster(volcano)))
head(d)
            x         y layer
1 0.008196721 0.9942529   100
2 0.024590164 0.9942529   100
3 0.040983607 0.9942529   101
4 0.057377049 0.9942529   101
5 0.073770492 0.9942529   101
6 0.090163934 0.9942529   101
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use the `row` and `col` command:

```
library(raster)
data(volcano)

df <- data.frame(
  x = as.vector(col(volcano)), 
  y = (yy <- as.vector(row(volcano)))[length(yy):1],
  val = as.vector(volcano)
)
```

`raster` rescales the range to `0` - `1`, if not specified differently, so we would to have to do this too:

```
## rescale
df$x <- with(df, (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
df$y <- with(df, (y - min(x)) / (max(y) - min(y)))
```

Finally lets check, that the results are the same:

```
 ## Using raster df1 <- data.frame(rasterToPoints(raster(volcano)))

 cols <- colorRampPalette(c('white', "blue",'red')) df$col <-
 cols(20)[as.numeric(cut(df$val, breaks = 20))] df1$col <-
 cols(20)[as.numeric(cut(df1$layer, breaks = 20))]

 par(mfrow = c(1, 2)) plot(df[, 1:2], col = df$col, pch = 20, main =
 "matrix")

 plot(df1[, 1:2], col = df1$col, pch = 20, main = "raster")
```

[image]

### Note:

While the results appear the same visually, they are **not**. The resolution of the `raster` command is most likely different, and hence there are different `nrow`s for `df` and `df1`.

Comment: Thanks. Your function is >10x faster than raster method for volcano. Mine seems to beat yours for bigger matrices (i.e. >1000^2).

I think the raster conversion does however preserve data resolution: `identical(volcano, as.matrix(raster(volcano))) == TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

Faster for large matrices:

```
data.frame(
  x = rep(1:ncol(m), each=nrow(m)), 
  y = rep(nrow(m):1, ncol(m)),
  val = as.vector(m)
)
```